# Who are high school juniors and seniors in US?

Tags: word-meaning

An advertisement:

> The Howard Neverov Creative Writing Awards, sponsored by Washington University in St. Louis.
>   Open to high school juniors and seniors 3 prizes of $250 each both in fiction and in poetry. Students may send one typed entry in each genre.
>   Entries must be postmarked by March 15, 2009...

Please, answer the questions:
1. Who are high school juniors and seniors in US?
2. What did they mean writing "one typed entry in each genre"?
3. What are "Entries" in that context?
4. What is "to be postmarked"?

Comment: That's the (late) poet Howard Nemerov. Note the spelling.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. For your first question, see  *[Are there other names for students according to their year - except of "sophomore"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109345/are-there-other-names-for-students-according-to-their-year-except-of-sophomor)*

Answer (score 2):

1. Generally 17 & 18 year olds in their next-to-last and their last year of high school.
2. One in fiction, one in poetry. Typed on typewriter or printed from computer, vs hand written. Probably to make them easier to read.
3. The entries are the story and/or the poem.
4. Must be accepted by the US Post Office. (the postmark across the stamp showing the letter was accepted for delivery).

Comment: postmarked means stamped with a postmark by the post office with its official stamp, giving the date, time and place a letter or mailed item is mailed.

Answer (score 2):

An **entry** in the context of a contest refers to the item submitted for consideration by the judges.  Contestants **enter** a contest, and we say that the item has been **entered for consideration**, hence the noun **entry**.